# Is eating fruits in an empty stomach healthier?

Tags: fruit

http://www.snopes.com/food/warnings/fruit.asp

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/11/12/the-best-way-to-eat-fruit_n_2114888.html?ir=India

http://www.fruitsandveggiesmorematters.org/eating-fruit-on-an-empty-stomach

debunk this while there is a plethora of sites supporting this claim. What's the bottom line? I am not referring to "combining fruits", I am just plain interested in say, is it healthier to eat an apple on an empty stomach or after a meal ?

Comment: Just to clarify, what type of evidence are you looking for? Also, could you please add links to a few sites supporting the claim? (and maybe add little excerpts from the different sites highlighting what is being claimed and/or debunked)

Comment: Already asked on this site: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16253/is-eating-fruits-separately-on-an-empty-stomach-healthier but still awaiting an answer.